# JavaScript Substring Returning Error

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I am using Joomla and attempting to use the `substring()` function to pull out the first 4 characters of my string.  The issue I am having is that I get an error of

This is my syntax - how should I change it so that it functions in my Joomla set-up?

> Uncaught TypeError: phpdate.substring is not a function

Here is syntax:

```
<?php
  $randardate = '20160301';
?>
<script>
  var phpdate = <?php echo $randardate; ?>;
  var yearfromphpdate = phpdate.substring(0,4);
</script>
```

Comment: Your PHP evaluates to `var phpdate = 20160301;` which isn't a string.

Comment: var phpdate = '<?php echo $randardate; ?>';

Comment: `var yearfromphpdate = phpdate.toString().substring(0,4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are pre processing a javascript file with PHP, without quotes your javascript file would look something like

```
var phpdate = 20160301;
```

You need to add quotations like this

```
var phpdate = '<?php echo $randardate; ?>';
```

So that when PHP is done processing your file, it will be a string, not an int.

```
var phpdate = '20160301';
```

Your stacktrace is being thrown because substring expects a string, not an int.

Answer (score 1):

Add quotation to make phpdate a string.

`var phpdate = '<?php echo $randardate; ?>';`